# Unicorn+Nginx concurrency and data duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, concurrency, unicorn

I have 4 Nginx workers and 4 unicorn workers. We hit a concurrency issue in some of our models that validate unique names. We are getting duplicated names when we send multiple requests at the same time on the same resource. For instance if we send around 10 requests to create Licenses we get duplicated serial_numbers...

Here's some context:

Model (simplified)

```
class License < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :serial_number, :uniqueness => true
end
```

Unicorn.rb

```
APP_PATH = '.../manager'

worker_processes 4
working_directory APP_PATH # available in 0.94.0+

listen ".../manager/tmp/sockets/manager_rails.sock", backlog: 1024
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true # uncomment to listen to TCP port as well

timeout 600
pid "#{APP_PATH}/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{APP_PATH}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path "#{APP_PATH}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"

preload_app true

GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true if GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=)

check_client_connection false

run_once = true

before_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
  MESSAGE_QUEUE.close
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
end
```

Nginx.conf (simplified)

```
worker_processes 4;

events {
  multi_accept off;
  worker_connections 1024;
  use epoll;
  accept_mutex off;
}

upstream app_server {
  server unix:/home/blueserver/symphony/manager/tmp/sockets/manager_rails_write.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

try_files $uri @app;

location @app {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_connect_timeout      600;
  proxy_send_timeout         600;
  proxy_read_timeout         600;
  proxy_pass http://app_server;
}
```

Every time I send multiple requests (more than 4+) to create Licenses I get some duplicates. I understand why. It's because each unicorn process doesn't have a resource with the serial_number created yet. So, it allow to create it multiple times...

ActiveRecord is validating the uniqueness of the field at the process level rather than a database level. One workaround could be moving the validations to the database (but it will be very cumbersome and hard to maintain).

Another workaround is to limit the write requests (POST/PUT/DELETE) to only one unicorn and have multiple unicorns to reply to read requests (GET). Something like this in the location in Nginx...

```
# 4 unicorn workers for GET requests
proxy_pass http://app_read_server;

# 1 unicorn worker for POST/PUT/DELETE requests
limit_except GET {
  proxy_pass http://app_write_server;
}
```

we are currently using that. It fixes the concurrency issue. However, one write server is not enough to reply at peak times and its creating a bottleneck.

Any idea to solve the concurrency and scalability issues with Nginx+Unicorn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you can go two ways:

- use unique index for unique key column(via migration) and catch appropriate exception;
- maintain the database constraints in a way described [here](http://hatoishi.net/articles/postgresql-constraints-in-rails/) and catch appropriate exception as well.

or use PostureSQL transaction with isolation level "serialised" which is basically transforms parallel translations into consecutive ones as it was described by Andrey Kryachkov early.

Comment: There are too many models using uniqueness so it will require a lot of changes. Seems like psql transaction are more suitable if I find a way to generalize it

Comment: Actually, I ended up adding indices via a migration. The official Rails API suggested as well: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of-label-Concurrency+and+integrity

Comment: "via migration" is just an option. Anyway it's not important in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at transaction isolation. For example, PostgreSQL - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html.

Comment: I think it won't fix the issue since each unicorn process will execute the actions in a different transaction. Duplication will still be possible.

Comment: https://github.com/kryachkov/license_database
I have created sample app to illustrate my answer. Concurrent requests to FreeLicensesController allow creation of doubled FreeLicense records. Concurrent requests to PaidLicensesController do not allow it.

Comment: Indeed, it does work. Thanks for putting that together! Just some follow up questions... Is there a way to generalize the transaction isolation in the rails config (almost all our controllers will need it)? Would it affect performance greatly?

Comment: I'm afraid setting app-wide isolation level is impossible and I can't predict performance degradation of your app. I have rather loaded app, which heavily uses serializable isolation level and I don't see any performance issues